Problem using mmap package in footnote
For example,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mmap}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\footnote{test}
\end{document}

The characters map to \mathrm{t}\mathrm{e}\mathrm{s}\mathrm{t}. Why is that?


Removing \maketitle I get:

The characters map to test. So the problem is probably caused by \maketitle.

Changing mmap to cmap I get:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\title{}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\footnote{test}
\end{document}

The characters map to test as expected


Note that \usepackage[noTeX]{mmap} also maps to test, but that is probably undesired because then actual math will also be in unicode instead of LaTeX markup. Also it doesn't address the issue that something causes the package to think that the footnote is math roman.

try with \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}. Then the text font encoding is different from the math encoding. (The reason why it happens is that the tabular in the maketitle triggers the initialization of the math fonts and so the footnotesize font uses the math map.)
